# Bevel : How to reproduce the model profile

Tags: modeling

I'm modeling a beveled niche based on this model.
I'm beveling, but I can't find the right custom profile to reproduce the model.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you add a picture/drawing showing the cross section of the profile you are expecting ? It is very difficult to estimate what would be *right* for you from the provided model...

Comment: @StefLAncien I  added it to my question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[image]

I've prefered a bevel modifier as it is not destructive and so easier to tune.

From the arch, without the bevel, give a loop cut, move it a bit in front axis of the arch, and assign it a bevel weight.

[image]

Then add the bevel modifier and set it to weight.

The bevel shape has to be done diagonaly, with enought segments.

Remember you can change the handle types, in order to make flat parts:

[image]

[image] (Blender 4.0)

Comment: Thank yo for helping but I cant reproduce the bevel. I gived a loop cut and moved it to the front axis and assign a weight. When I add a modifier to the sphere I have nothing...

Comment: Have you set "limit method" to "weight" for the bevel modifier?

Comment: Yes. I think I dont know what to select before adding the modifier.

Comment: I've added an example file. Please check it to see what is missing in your setting.

Comment: Thank you. My arch is a bit different. See  [<img src="https://blend-exchange.com/embedImage.png?bid=NQbr2bOm" />](https://blend-exchange.com/b/NQbr2bOm/)

Comment: In your file, bevel modifier fails because you have also assigned a bevel weight at the bottom part (under the niche). Remove bevel weight for this part.

Comment: It works great !

Answer (score 4):

You could create a curve that follows the main shape, give it a low resolution:

[image]

Create a second curve that will be your bevel, it looks like something like that:

[image]

Select your first curve and under *Geometry > Bevel > Object*, select the second curve:

[image]

If you are glad with the result, <kbd>RMB</kbd> and convert the curve to mesh, merge by distance and bevel the edges if necessary:

[image]